# Cannot build ionic app for ios after installing cordova sqlite storage plugin

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have problem when building my ionic app for ios(cordova ios v3.8.0) after installing cordova sqlite storage plugin (v1.4.8). When I run "ionic build ios" command it get following error.

"2016-11-02 16:23:41.746 xcodebuild[10689:292509] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 56. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.

2016-11-02 16:23:41.746 xcodebuild[10689:292509] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 56. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.

2016-11-02 16:23:41.747 xcodebuild[10689:292509] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected character / at line 1" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character / at line 1, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Missing ';' on line 56" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Missing ';' on line 56}}"

Then when i try open xcode project it show following error.

"*********.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed."

Without sqlite plugin this process works.

cordova v5.0.0
xcode version 7.3.1
Ionic v2.1.1